# I'm no longer getting subscription emails from Careers 2

Tags: support, jobs, email-notification

I'm no longer getting subscription emails relate to the search criteria that I set up.
I checked whether new jobs that meet my criteria and I found a lot.

Any thing is going wrong?

Answer (score 6):

We’ve updated our search algorithm a bit. The search terms you have in your [subscriptions](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/subscribe) result in a long “and” query, and that combination of technologies is unlikely to *all* occur in any single job.

You can update it to an “or” [query](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=java+or+iphone+or+ruby) to get better results.